# mysql query in php with more conditions from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

First of all, I am absolute beginner with PHP and SQL.
I have two tables: `users(userID, fullname, username, email, pass, userlevel)` and `games(gameID, userID, club, result, created_time)`. 
In table `games` I have `userID`, same as in table `users`, but it's not foreign key. When I do this query in MySQL it works fine:

```
DELETE FROM games 
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE userlevel=2 
AND users.userID=games.userID)
```

It removes anything that `users.userID` matches with `games.userID` and if that user is `userlevel 2`.

I need this in PHP, but only difference would be that `userID` will match user's ID that is logged,and user will be able to delete only the data that is input with its `userID`.

Also, how to allow everyone else, with `userlevel 1` to be able to delete everything in table games no matter who entered on the same submit?

I have this, but its not working....it keeps givin' me the same error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in
>   C(...)

```
require ('db_con.php');     
session_start(); 
$userID=$_SESSION["UserID"];

if (isset($_POST['delete'])){                       
        $stmt=$con->prepare("DELETE FROM games WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT FROM users AS u WHERE u.userID = ? AND u.userlevel = 2 "));        

       $stmt->bind_param("s",$_POST['userID']));
       $stmt->execute();
}
```

Even if I put `$userlevel=2` and replace in query `u.userlevel = '$userlevel'`, it gives the same error...

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. 
thanx!

Comment: First - fix this `$stmt=$con->prepare("DELETE FROM games WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT FROM users AS u WHERE u.userID = ? AND u.userlevel = 2 "));` Extra `)` here. Next - check errors.

Comment: fixed!....its still the same error...

Answer (score 0):

userID is an integer value. Change `bind_param` line to

```
$stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
```

One reason **prepare()** can fail is -

`if the sql statement sent to it is not valid in the current DB. 
 prepare() will then return false`.

Eg -  if the table name is not correct **or one or more field in the query does not exist**.

Answer (score 0):

You got a bracket mismatch:

```
    $stmt=$con->prepare("DELETE FROM games WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT FROM users AS u WHERE u.userID = ? AND u.userlevel = 2 "));
```

should really be

```
$stmt=$con->prepare("DELETE FROM games WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users AS u WHERE u.userID = ? AND u.userlevel = 2 )");
```

Anyway, the error you received means that `$con->prepare` did not return an object. Most likely it returned `false`. I assume you are using PDO, so according to the docs:

> If the database server cannot successfully prepare the statement, PDO::prepare() returns FALSE or emits PDOException (depending on error handling).

So that's the case here. Your MySQL-server was unable to bind the statement. In order to debug this better (e.g. see more helpful error messages) set PDO to throw exceptions on errors.

You could probably do it like this:

```
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Just add that line right after you connect to the database.

Comment: here is error after bind param : Errormessage: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM users AS u WHERE u.userID = ? AND u.userlevel= 2)' at line 1

Comment: You'd also miss an asterisk in your query. Did you change that too?

Answer (score 0):

i found the error, here is the wright code:

$stmt=$con->prepare("DELETE FROM games WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.userID = ? AND users.userlevel = 2 )");

but its not working what i wanted, it deleted all from my games table :D
i guess, SELECT * FROM has to be specific!